# Javascript never gets called

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Any reason for the Javascript is NOT firing ?

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<script type="text/javascript">

function ChangeDisplay() 
{
    alert("Changing");

    document.getElementById('warningDiv').innerHTML = "<h1>Change Text</h1>";
    setTimeout(finalize,6000); 
} 

function finalize() 
{ 
    alert("Done");
    document.getElementById('warningDiv').innerHTML="<h1>Done</h1>"; 
}​
</script>

<h2>
    Welcome to ASP.NET!
</h2>
<p>
    <div id="warningDiv">Hello World</div>
    ​
</p>
<script>
    window.onload = setTimeout(ChangeDisplay, 3000); 
</script>
```

Comment: where is `WarnTheUser` defined?

Comment: Made a mistake when typing, changed the original. Still not working

Comment: Should `window.onload = setTimeout(ChangeDisplay, 3000);` be `window.onload = setTimeout("ChangeDisplay()", 3000);` ...not exactly sure off the top of my head, but looks funny compared to http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: @Chase Both passing a function and string is valid. However, passing a function is the recommended way as the string must be parsed, which basically requires an editional eval call. And w3schools.com are not exactly the best source...

Comment: Made a fiddle for this, but it seem to work...perhaps the issue is elsewhere. http://jsfiddle.net/UsUuG/

Comment: Yes ..on the fiddle it works. That's why i also put ASP.NET on the tags. That's where the problem is (:

Comment: Ok, just thoughts. Is `window.onload` really cross-browser? Doesn't it confuse the browser that the functions are in `<script type="text/javascript">` while the handler is only in `<script>`? It shouldn't, but...

Comment: If I remove the <script> it just shows as TEXT "window.onload = setTimeout(ChangeDisplay(), 3000);"

Comment: @Developer of course :) I meant adding the language specification to the script tag. But if you say that this example works in a fiddle, then the problem may really be elsewhere in your site.

Answer (score 3):

> Any reason for the Javascript is NOT firing ?

Yes, `WarnTheUser` does not exist and the other functions are not called.

**Edit**: Maybe it's a browser issue, you could use jQuery, maybe it makes a difference:

```
$(document).ready(function() { setTimeout(ChangeDisplay, 3000) });
```

or

```
$(window).load(function() { setTimeout(ChangeDisplay, 3000) });
```

I don't think that it's an ASP.NET issue. You haven't shown much ASP.NET code anyway, are you using Ajax?

Comment: sorry the bottom supposed to call the "ChangeDisplay" ..see changes on original

Comment: @Developer: You could try jQuery(edited my answer).

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

Well, it seems that

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
   window.onload = setTimeout(ChangeDisplay(), 3000); 
</script>
```

does work, so THANKS ALL for the various tips.

All ...minus the one that did the "-1" on the post.
Never understood why people do that.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. `ChangeDisplay` returns void, so of course in this case, it's being fired immediately (not in 3 seconds) and it's passing `void` to `setTimeout`...